# Httrack convert wordpress to HTML

Tags: html, css, httrack

I am trying to covert a wordpress website into a simple html/css website but the problem is that whenever I use httrack, it downloads the whole wordpress files making it hard for me to extract the simple html/css files
Is there away to solve that using httrack? or any other method?

Answer (score 0):

in the httrack url list, add the list of pages you actually need. For Example, if the website you wish to extract is abc.com, then instead of just writing abc.com mention the pages you want 
For Example abc.com/index.php abc.com/about.php

This will reduce the unnecessary files required. Also, the httrack tries to create folder similar to the host. So this is the max that you can do. Inspect Element goes handy while editing these mirrored sites.